# Achart Engine Bar Chart setMarginColor - how to add the image to the margin?

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

i have a graph generated as below [image]

I have couple of problems here:

1) how to remove that black border
2) how to add gradient to the bars.
3) how to remove the space below the legends.

this is my code:

For Background problem this is my code:
After adding the drawable i am facing this problem and also i want to add an image to that and not color, i have tried with white color it doesent show black border? why is that?

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
        multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(R.drawable.background);
```

For gradient i tried like this but didnt work:

```
samplseries.setGradientEnabled(true);
samplseries.setGradientStart(Color.rgb(120,188,219));
samplseries.setGradientStop(Color.rgb(74, 155, 192));
```

Comment: You're always asking three questions in a single one :)

Comment: Please help me on this i am ready to make some changes in the source code also :) i am stuck from a very long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I suggest you avoid transparent color for background.
2. You tried the code for that and it didn't even compile. The `setGradientStart` and `setGradientStop` methods expect two parameters: the value to start / stop the color and the color.
3. `renderer.setFitLegend(true);`

Comment: ok 3 rd solution worked for me, can you please help on the other 2 issues also, please dont mind

Comment: Man, my answer 1 is for your question 1. Answer 2 is for question 2. Answer 3 is for question 3.

Comment: this is my problem as i said yesterday i am trying to hide the bars wen we scroll to left, i tried with setting to white colr for margin it works fine but i want to add image to it how to do that?

Comment: ok but can we make some changes so that i can do it, can you suggest me what to change? or add to make that work

Comment: No. It has no value for ACE, so I won't add such thing.

Comment: Sorry i was not on my desk,No No you please dont make any changes but i am asking you to suggest something for me to acheive that

Comment: You can probably modify AbstractChart.drawBackground.

Comment: ok if i mofify that will i be able to solve that 1st issue? and hide the bars wen the user scrolls to left?

Comment: ok atleast tell me how can i hide the bars wen moving to left thats enough i will take of rest

Comment: because what i see is that the x axis labels are not visble , imean it hide but why not the bars wen we scroll to left

Comment: no idea as far as i know i havent done that,if so i will remove that

Comment: ok i have upvoted that , i have found one more bug related to pie chart check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730376/achart-engine-piechart-2nd-color-starts-from-off-center-is-it-a-bug ... let me know on that